# Preventing unused spare hdd from spinning up during suspend and shutdown

Tags: linux, hard-drive, shutdown, suspend, spinup

I recently replaced my sata hdd with an ssd, and keeping the hdd in as a spare. It's not used, not event mounted to filesystem. Yet, when suspending or shutting down the system, it quickly spins up, then down when power goes off.

How can i prevent the spare disk from spinning up upon suspend or shutdown?

I'm running mint petra(16) with 3.11.0-18 kernel, tlp for power management.

Comment: It sounds like its parking and unparking the HDD, somehting that is a device protocol. If this is the case, you cant' stop it, nor should you.

Comment: @LPChip but the disk is not running in anyway and had already spun down. It only spins up when the system is going down.

Comment: Yes, as I said, to move the head into parking mode. The system gives a shutdown event to the motherboard, which in term will send the controller an shutdown event, that the harddrives receive if they are connected by sata. They'll interpret this by moving the head into park position so the pc can be travelled around. same happens at startup to move the head out of park position.

Comment: If you're not using the drive then disconnect its power connector (or just remove the drive).